# Trying to find duplicate files within Python - Getting error global name not defined?

Tags: python

I am trying to find files, calculate their hash and hash to dictionary.  Trying to find duplicate files based on their hash.  I am not sure why I get this following error:

```
NameError: global name 'value_occurences' is not defined
```

---

```
import os
import hashlib 
import collections

# Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = 'C:\\Users\\kd\\prep'

def parsing_dir_files(rootDir):
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
        for fname in fileList:
            hash_of_files = hashlib.md5()
            hash_of_files.update(fname)
            hash_of_files = hash_of_files.hexdigest()

            data_dict = {fname:hash_of_files}

    return data_dict

def return_dups(file_list_dict):

    value_occurrences = collections.Counter(file_list_dict.values())
    filtered_dict = {key: value for key, value in file_list_dict.items()
                     if value_occurences[value] == 1}

    print (filtered_dict) 
    return filtered_dict

def main():
    file_list = parsing_dir_files(rootDir)
    dup_list = return_dups(file_list)
    print(dup_list)

main()
```

Comment: Can you please post complete error message? I mean on which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value_occurrences` not `value_occurences`,you forgot a `r`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake in the `if` condition. If you see the spelling in if and in first line of `return_dupes` function they are different. Correct it and it will work.